# Java popup trigger in Linux

Tags: java, linux, popup

I have an application in which you can do a right mouse button press and drag (as well as a left press and drag for different operations). However, when running this on linux, it seems that popup menus are triggered by a mousePressed and not a mouseReleased. This is resulting in every time I press the right mouse button to perform a drag, the popup menus are triggered (unlike windows, where it is mouseReleased).

Any thoughts on how to work around this?

thanks.

EDIT: Posting code

Code for popup menu

```
// this is called from mousePressed and mouseReleased
if (e.isPopupTrigger() && !e.isConsumed()) {
    // show the popup menu
}
```

This code is what is called on the right mouse press/drag (this is 3rd party code, but it is open source so I can change as needed)

```
// this is called on all mouse events
if (buttonAction.mouseButton != 0)
{
    // handle the event
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, use `isPopupTrigger()`, as shown [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html).

Addendum:

> it appears `isPopupTrigger` is triggered on `mousePressed` in linux.

Yes, it's the same on Mac OS X. You have to call `isPopupTrigger()` from both `mousePressed()` and `mouseReleased()`. There's a related example in [`GraphPanel`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel).

Comment: I am, it appears isPopupTrigger is triggered on mousePressed in linux.

Comment: Right, so if I'm using a 3rd party library that performs some non popup action when the right mouse is pressed and dragged, does this mean that the popup menu will always show when trying to do that other action?

Comment: I just tried `GraphPanel` on Windows, and I see what you mean. Does the third party API expose its selection model?

Comment: Yes, I have full access to the code, so I can modify anything relating to selection I need to.

Comment: I don't see a way for one gesture to evoke two different behaviors without some other cue. Using `consume()/isConsumed()` may be one way, but you can always commandeer the third button or use a modifier key as a signal to resolve which meaning is intended. For reference, on Mac OS X, `isPopupTrigger()` returns `true` when button one is pressed with the control key.

Comment: yes, I will have to likely build in some more advanced mechanism, such as holding the control key

Answer (score 1):

MouseEvent.isPopupTrigger(). Returns whether or not this mouse event is the popup menu trigger event for the platform.

edit - : You need to make the check in both mousePressed for linux, and mouseReleased for windows.

Comment: Right, I am doing that. My problem is that every time I press the right mouse button to do the right-press/drag action, the popup menu shows (which I don't want).

Comment: Would you mind posting the code from both of those methods? Hard to tell what you're doing after/before doing the check without that.

Comment: Going by the logic you posted, it's always going to show the popup menu. You're checking to see if it was a popup trigger (which it will be) and then your comment reads " // show the popup menu
". If you don't want the popup to show, then just return inside of that condition instead of showing the popup.

Comment: Unless you plan plan on doing more as a result of the mouse press or release. In that case you can just consume the event and do whatever it is that you wanted to do. So something like:

if(e.isPopupTrigger()){e.consume();}
//do fancy jazz

Comment: One thing I could do is set a flag on mousePressed, and then on mouseReleased show the popup menu if the event hasn't been consumed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct procedure in your case should be to unify where and when to show the popup. As a drag event, if exist, follows a press event you should avoid writting logic for showing the popup in the press event *(and then also write logic in the press event for showing the popup)*. Some users feel good navigating the popup while holding the popup button, and some other users just don't care or don't know. But in your case, you won't be able to navigate the popup menu while dragging without adding extra code.

My way would we to manage the logic to always show the popup on the release event. Entering a release event after a drag should be enough information to know that the popup shouldn't be visible. And of course, always if you can change and modify the source.