# Problems with KeyEvents

Tags: scala, listener, scala-swing

I'm wondering why the following code doesn't work:

```
object Main extends SimpleSwingApplication {

  val dim = new Dimension(500, 110)

  def top = new MainFrame {
    contents = new FlowPanel{
      listenTo(keys, mouse.clicks)
      reactions += {
        case MouseClicked(_,_,_,_,_) => println("Mouse clicked")
        case KeyPressed(_, Key.C, _, _) => println("C pressed")
        case KeyTyped(_, Key.C, _, _) => println("C typed")
        case KeyReleased(_, Key.C, _, _) => println("C released")
      }
    }
    size = dim
  }

}
```

The mouse clicks will be recognized, but the keystrokes won't. I also tried different keys or modifiers, but nothing seems to have an effect. What am I doing wrong?

(In the unlikely case that this might have something to do with the environment: I'm running this code with SBT on Windows 7)

Comment: Just as a side note: it's not so unlikely as you might think: I had problems with swing popup cause on different OS [it behaves differently](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5736872/298389).

Comment: Maybe because a panel isn't made for keyevents? Does it work for a TextField?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11817490/770361), it seems you need to include the line

```
focusable = true
```

for your `FlowPanel`. It should then work.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for posting this kinda duplicate question. (I guess the problem was that I was searching with [scala-swing])

Comment: @SHildebrandt I find Google works better than the search on this site!